# How to find the number of different visited positions on 2D grid given a sequence of movements

Tags: c#, logic, bidirectional

I have a problem:

Given an infinite 2D grid and given a set of commands (of the type up, down, left or right) given by the user (of any length), how to know how many **different** positions were visited?

I'll be trying to solve this probably in C#, however the language has little importance her as it might be a problem of logic more than programming.

I was thinking of having a hash-set and keep adding tuples of the visited positions, but this approach comes with some complexity which might not be required and in order to be infinite it would require the creation of new hash-sets every time it reaches its maximum capacity of stored positions.

I'm trying to think of general patterns of movement sequences (e.g. Up,Down) within the complete sequence which I could remove and add some number of visited positions to the total. By parsing the complete sequence looking for such patterns I would keep adding to the number of visited cases.

Another similar approach would be to set the initial value of visited positions to the number of movements +1 (initial position) and look for sequence patterns that would subtract from the total.

Any idea which approach would be:

(1) Computationally more efficient
(2) Logically more simple
(3) More reliable (less prone to failing - Ideally it would be perfect in the sense that it would always give the correct number of different visited positions given any sequence of movements)

Comment: Simply count the number of locations visited one.  If you have length L than maximum grid size is L by L.  So create a grid with a visited property.  Then when you are done count the number of locations visited.  Algorithm Is NxN.  You could put locations into a list as you visited each location.  You would then have to sort to get number of duplicates.  This would be N/2.  Third method is to put locations into a hash.  Every move would be added to hash.  Algorithm would be Log2(N).  All are 100% reliable.

Comment: That's similar to what I was thinking. Thanks.